# What is the font style of this one?

Tags: fonts, font-face, truetype

[image: Serial Label]

Please help me identify this font style. I really need this for my program.

Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that's a printer-specific font in your image. The closest I could find was [Wearetrippin Short](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/t26/wearetrippin/short/glyphs.html?render=old), by the T-26 font foundry. Sample below:

[image: glyphs 0-4 of Wearetrippin Short font]

Comment: @shark Glad I could help. If you're ever looking again, MyFonts has this [great tool called WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) that lets you upload an image of a font and then gives you the closest matching digital fonts.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be Consolas? But it may be a custom font for the particular printer that was used. You could also search [Google fonts](https://www.google.com/fonts) for something similar...

UPDATE:

Check the doco [here](http://www.sato-drucker.ch/PDF/M84Pro.pdf) and [here](http://www.satoeurope.com/Uploads/Files/Downloads/Bibliotheek/Documentatie/Handleidingen/OM-M84Pro-en.pdf):

```
12 proportional, mono-spaced and outline
fonts.Code page 858, others available.
Internal CG Triumvirate® & CG Times®
fonts
plus downloaded TrueType®
fonts, scalable
from 8 to 72 points.
```

Comment: I am using a SATO M84Pro printer...

Comment: I've tried CG Triumvirate and CG Times but its not the same. So I try to research about some font but I haven't found same as above.

Comment: Closest I've got is Inconsolas from google fonts.. But is still not the same.